piping echo into read with and without while loop
why does a echo | read behave differently to echo | while read?
$ echo -e "1\t2\t3" | read a b c; echo "$a-$b-$c"
--

$ echo -e "1\t2\t3" | while read a b c; do echo "$a-$b-$c"; done
1-2-3



ah, yes, bash, pipes and subshells, forgot about that. note that in the first case the piped statement ends with the semicolon after the read but in the second case the whole right-hand side runs in the sub-shell!

See bash FAQ #1.
